# Reading a tab delimited file and concatenate selective columns in Ruby

Tags: ruby, text-parsing

I have a tab delimited file, in which the first 10 columns are always present and stay at same position, but after the 10th column, the number of columns can change. I want to retain the first 10 columns as is and concatenate the rest of the columns into one column separated by `|`.

Here is the sample data:

> columns: col1 col2 ... col 10 col11 col12 col13
>
> Values:   1    2    ... 10     11    12    13

Result:

> Columns: col1 col2 ... col10 **col11|col12|col13**
>
> Values: 1     2    ...  10    **11  | 12  | 13**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ruby's [split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method - it takes an optional `limit` parameter. Assuming your data is in a variable `row` for each line:

```
values = row.split("\t", 11)
```

Example (with the variable part starting at column 3 for brevity):

```
s = "1\t2\t3\t4" 
cols = s.split("\t", 3) 
# result: ["1", "2", "3\t4"]
```

Then you can change the last element in place:

```
cols[2] = cols.last.gsub("\t", "|")
# cols is now: ["1", "2", "3|4"]
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert the concatenated columns into key value pair in the same example?

Answer (score 2):

You could start with something like

```
IO.foreach('path/to/file') do |line|
  splits = line.split("\t")

  col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 = splits


  col11 = splits[10..-1].join('|')
end
```